# saiku mdx performance issues with * operator for crossjoin

Tags: mdx, mondrian, saiku

Can anyone explain why

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Quantity]})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY ([Time].[Years].Members * [Markets].[City].Members * [Product].[Product].Members * [Customers].[Customer].Members) ON ROWS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
```

is so much slower than this:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Quantity]})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY CrossJoin([Time].[Years].Members, CrossJoin([Markets].[City].Members, CrossJoin([Product].[Product].Members, [Customers].[Customer].Members))) ON ROWS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
```

I would like to use the * operator to make crossjoins but it seems so much slower. Any idea why and what can I do?

Comment: ...and if you change the order of the hierarchies cross-joined in the first script?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the order is important:
http://community.altiusconsulting.com.ourwindowsnetwork.com/blogs/altiustechblog/archive/2008/06/13/mdx-crossjoin-performance.aspx

Just in case the above link dies in the future it basically compares the two following AdvWks scripts performance:

QUERY 1

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.PerfmonTest AS 
Count( 
    Crossjoin( [Promotion].[Promotions].[Promotion] ,
        Filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Customer], RIGHT([Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember.Name,5) = "Smith") 
    )
) 
SELECT Measures.PerfmonTest ON Columns 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

QUERY 2

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.PerfmonTest AS 
Count( 
    Crossjoin( 
        Filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Customer], RIGHT([Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember.Name,5) = "Smith")
        ,[Promotion].[Promotions].[Promotion] ) 
    ) 
SELECT Measures.PerfmonTest ON Columns 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Hmm. Interesting point. I didn't realize it earlier. If my assumption is correct and the inner most subquery evaluates first and then goes on to the outermost, then yes, the order might be diff. In the first query in OP, is the natural order of execution left to right?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti not sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098346/execution-order-of-crossjoined-hierarchies

Comment: @whytheq, my initial queries have the same order but still there is a huge difference in performance...the only difference between the two is that in the first one I used the * operator instead of the crossjoin function