# Execution order of crossjoined hierarchies

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

If I create a set of tuples via the following crossjoin which hierarchy is joined to which first?

```
hierA * hierB * hierC
```

If I know that the count of non empty members in A and B are significantly less than the count of members in C then should this influence the order?

Comment: Maybe this is somehow connected with an old Mosha's topic: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/12/06/performance-of-multiplication-in-mdx.aspx ("you need to use the sparser variable as first operand and denser variable as the second operand")

Comment: @AlexPeshik ...and if there are more than two?

Comment: sorry, I don't have exact answer based on theory. I've just tested AdwWorks2012 Multidimentional and it shows 93.8 (a * b * c) vs 98.2 (c * a * b) ms average results (10 times tested, cold cache), where a, b - sparse, c - dense. no significant improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the execution system used, i.e. how crossjoining on axis is optimized by compiler.

Anyway, you will get real boost only if you first reduce cube size with subselect - it will prevent crossjoining non-matching points:

```
select
 { [Measures].[X] } on 0,
 { [DimA].[A] * [DimB].[B] } on 1
From ( 
             select { [DimB].[B].members}   on 0 
             from CubeA
           )
```